# Does SEO value get transfered when a 301 redirect points to a page that has another canonical?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have this scenario: Page A is 301 redirected to another Page B, which has exactly the same content(automated process). But Page B has another `rel=canonical` Page, the Page C due to some parameters in the URL. Does the SEO value transferred from page A to page C?

I know that I could use `rel=canonical` from Page A to page C, but let’s say I can’t do it for that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no such comment by google that "rel=canonical" tag pass link juice.The real canonical tag is only use to tell "google crawler" about the Duplicate pages. So it is hard to reach at the conclusion that it gives you some benefit or not. But in many discussions it is seemed that webmasters will advise to avoid this thing,see the answer by @Dr. Peter J. Meyers at [moz's community](https://moz.com/community/q/do-canonical-tags-pass-all-of-the-link-juice-onto-the-url-they-point-to).

So we advise you to add 301 redirection to an non canonical page.

Answer (score -1):

Remember you are redirecting from Page A to Page B because you are instructing user that
 1. Page A is removed , you can find the content in Page B (or,) 
 2. Page A has not a good content, so I am redirecting you to Page B.

Thing from User perspective. Giving a needful content is valuable.

About rel=canonical:

you are instructing google to rank the page C than Page A, Page B because you thought ranking Page C is good and it has original content related to the keyword. Thats all

Now the decision is yours

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  You just explain how redirects and canonicals work but don't say at all how they pass SEO value, let alone in combination.

Comment: Dont worry about this. Yes the page rank will pass

Answer (score -1):

A 301 Redirect instructs search engines that the content on the requested page (Page A) has been moved to Page B on a permanent basis. As browsers receive this code, you’ll be automatically redirected to the new Page B, mentioned together with the 301 status code.   a The 301 redirect code is implemented when your domain is moved permanently, or when web pages have been replaced or moved permanently, or when your web page content is expired, or 404 error wants to point to another, relevant page. The SEO value isn't transferred like adding money to your bank account. The new page will grow it's own value as it is found.

On the other hand, a `rel="canonical"` attribute doesn’t redirect a visitor to the new URL. Instead, it signals search engines which page to index in SERPs when duplicated content appears within a site.  This attribute is used when the content is duplicated or similar on both impacted pages, and both remain visible to visitors. It is also used at the time of content syndication and when it’s impossible to implement 301 redirects.

Using these practices may be good for SEO. Which one you choose depends on your own choice. Remember to consider the impact on your site overall as well as the impacted pages. Review your analytics results before making changes so you do not lose the momentum from popular pages.

Comment: "The SEO value isn't transferred like adding money to your bank account. The new page will grow it's own value as it is found."  -- Actually, the conventional SEO wisdom is that using a 301 permanent redirect does transfer the link juice and much of the SEO value from one URL to the other.